# Test automation program

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber

There is a program out there that I can't for the life of me remember the name of. I'm not sure if this is the correct forum to ask this but thought I'd give it a shot and see if anyone can help me out.

Program Description:

This program is for writing and running test automation. It allows you to write the steps of the test in English.

Example (scenario: posting stack overflow question):

1. Enter title 'XXX'
2. Enter Description
3. Enter tag 'X'
4. Click Post button

After entering the test steps in English sentences you can run the test. The test will come back yellow, saying that not all the steps are automated yet and create stub methods for each of the 4 steps mentioned above.

You can then go through the work of automating the different steps and running the tests.

Sorry if this sounds vague, but I remember looking at this piece of software last year and can't seem to find it or remember the name anymore.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's the Ruby Gem [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/).

Answer (score 0):

That's [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io).

It will warn you if you have undefined scenarios or steps, and it will suggest some code snippets for those steps, as shown in this ["10 min tutorial"](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).